# Is it ok to contact old interviewers?

Tags: interviewing, applications

Some time ago I applied for a job. I went through 2 rounds but then got another offer and withdrew my application for the first position. The position I accepted resulted not to have much to do with what was advertised and what I accepted.

Before the interview at the first company I got contacted by a manager of the company. His contact only served to arrange the interview.

Would it be ok for me to send him my CV again asking whether he might be interested in me again? Or does it come across as very desperate?

Comment: How long have it been since you withdrew?

Comment: Nothing ventured, nothing gained

Comment: `Would it be ok for me to send him my CV again asking whether he might be interested in me again? ` - Yes. Why not? `Or does it come across as very desperate?` - Why would someone looking for a job seem desperate? How would they even know about your current situation?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is fine to do this. You will seem interested in the company, even more so if you explain why you are reaching out to him again (EG: I liked the idea of the work you do, I enjoy this company etc).

When we look for jobs we have to go out of our comfort zone slightly, but it doesn't seem desperate. If they had not interviewed you the first time, and you contacted them again and again asking for a job, that would be a different story.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on how small your area is and how long ago you withdrew your application (and maybe how professional you were when you withdrew it), but in general it sounds fine.

Even if you do "come across as very desperate" (and I'm not convinced you will), then the worst possible outcome is they decide not to interview you. The best possible outcome is they interview you and offer you the job. Go for it.